# c++ trigger function when bool changes

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I have a bool value that is constantly streaming. I need to trigger a function when the bool becomes true, and another when the bool becomes false, but only once per change, so I cannot use a `while(true)` loop.

What is the best way in c++ to 'watch' a value and trigger when it changes?

Thank you.

Comment: Lookup for [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about this by setting a flagTrue variable and a flagFalse variable. When you encounter the first True, flagTrue changes from false to true and all following True booleans are ignored. Similarly, when you encounter your firat False, flagFalse would change from False to True and ignore all following False booleans. Also, when the boolean being checked changes from True to False, you will change flagTrue to False and similarly in the other case.
Example:

```
flagTrue = false
flagFalse = false
if (bool == true && flagTrue == false)
{
   // DoSomething
   flagTrue = true;
   flagFalse = false;
}
else if (bool == false && flagFalse == false)
{
   // DoSomething
   flagTrue = false;
   flagFalse = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (edited) So the opposite would be:

`if (bool == false&& flagFalse == False)
{
   // DoSomething
   flagTrue = False;
   flagFalse = True;
}`


Is that right?

Comment: I have added initialization. I believe they make this clearer. Yes, the converse you have added is correct. I have updated my code. Please check it out.

Comment: ah i see. Makes perfect sense. Thank you again!

Comment: You do not need two flags, one is sufficient: `static bool isActive = false; bool newVal = read(); if(newVal != isActive) { isActive = newVal; /* callback depending on isActive */ }`

Comment: @Aconcagua very good idea. Could you please share how you would go about initialization? I believe you would need three values, one default, one for True and one for False. This does not fit the requirement of booleans and you might have to use integers instead

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj You actually don't need any flag if you are doing it right. See my answer below for details.

Comment: std::atomic::exchange gives you the previous state information while being safe in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

struct trigger
{
  using closure_type = std::function<void()>;

  trigger(closure_type on_set, closure_type on_reset, bool initial_state = false)
  : _state { initial_state }
  , _on_set(std::move(on_set))
  , _on_reset(std::move(on_reset))
  {}

  void set() {
    if (not _state.exchange(true)) {
      _on_set();
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    if (_state.exchange(false)) {
      _on_reset();
    }
  }

  std::atomic<bool> _state;
  std::function<void()> _on_set;
  std::function<void()> _on_reset;
};

void has_set() {
  // you can marshall accross threads here by posting calls to a 
  // queue
  std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

void has_unset() {
  // you can marshall accross threads here by posting calls to a 
  // queue
  std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  trigger t { has_set, has_unset };

  t.set();
  t.set();

  t.reset();
  t.reset();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Observer Pattern. You could wrap your boolean in a helper class, that triggers an event whenever the boolean is set.

Example implementation of an observable bool:

```
#include <vector>

class Observer {
public:
    virtual void valueChanged() = 0;
};

class ObservableBool {
private:
    bool value;
    std::vector<Observer*> observers = std::vector<Observer*>();

public:
    bool getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    bool setValue(bool value) {
        bool changed = (value != this->value);
        this->value = value;
        if(changed) raiseEvent();
    }

    void addObserver(Observer* observer) {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    void removeObserver(Observer* observer) {
        observers.erase(std::find(observers.begin, observers.end, observer));
    }

private:
    void raiseEvent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size; ++i) {
            observers[i]->valueChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

This can be improved a lot. A really nice way would be to implement implicit conversion from and to bool (But be careful, overloadig the '=' operator for bool could be dangerous). You could template it to support arbitrary types instead of just bool, you should use smart pointer instead of raw pointers (`std::weak_ptr` would be best) and instead of a Observer class you should probably use function pointers to properly support lambdas. If you do it right you can use the class just like a normal boolean, with a small overhead when a new value is set. And by default, all reactions to a change are executed by the thread that changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's a slightly simpler solution if you just want to bang it out (like for testing):

```
/**
 * @brief Set a boolean variable.
 * @param b Pointer to the boolean variable.
 * @param value Set to this value.
 * @return Returns if the value was to be changed.
 */
bool set(bool* b, bool value)
{
    // if b isn't going to change
    if (*b == value) return false;

    // if b is going to change
    else
    {
        *b = value;
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief A possible implementation
 */
int main()
{
    bool my_variable = false;

    while(true)
    {
        // Set my_variable and flag it if it changed
        bool changed = set(&my_variable, some_function());

        // check for changed
        if (changed)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This seems a bit less overkill than implementing boolean wrapper classes, triggers, and observer-patterns.